# Dojo select widget validation

Tags: validation, select, dojo, widget

I am using the Dojo select widget, and by default, I am displaying an empty option to user.

I am setting required attribute to `true`, but Dojo validation is not making / changing background color for the selection when form is submitted,but still it is applying CSS style for other validation text boxes.

I tried to apply my own custom style, but Dojo is overridding those. Is it possible to do required validation on select widget and get coloring?

Comment: Which widget are you talking about, dijit.form.FilteringSelect or dijit.form.Select?

Comment: i am using dijit.form.select.

Comment: The issue I think you're experiencing is that the blank option is technically a valid choice so far as `required=true` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of how required is used in the dojo tests (http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Select.html). If you define the "empty" option without any value that option will be invalid if required = true, like this:

```
<option>&nbsp;</option>
```

If you define the options programmatically you define the "empty" option like this:

```
{label: "&nbsp;"}
```